# Passing string from one window to another using Signal

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am trying pass a string from First window to Second window using signal. I want the string to be shown after pressing the push button on the Second window. However, I am getting the following error:"TypeError: decorated slot has no signature compatible with clicked(bool)"

I am using Qt-designer to create First and Second window.
Below is the main code:

```
class First(QDialog):
    signal = pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(First, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_First()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Send)
        self.show()

    def Send(self):
        UserInput = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        foo = Second()
        self.signal.connect(foo.Receive)
        self.signal.emit(str(UserInput))
        self.ui = Second()

class Second(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Second, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Second()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Receive)
        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def Receive(self, strA):
        self.ui.label.setText(strA)
```

Here is the First.py:

```
class Ui_First(object):
    def setupUi(self, First):
        First.setObjectName("First")
        First.resize(195, 134)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(First)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 80, 111, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(First)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.retranslateUi(First)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(First)

    def retranslateUi(self, First):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        First.setWindowTitle(_translate("First", "First"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("First", "Send to Second"))
```

Here is the Second.py:

```
class Ui_Second(object):
    def setupUi(self, Second):
        Second.setObjectName("Second")
        Second.resize(195, 134)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Second)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 80, 111, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Second)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 40, 55, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Second)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Second)

    def retranslateUi(self, Second):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Second.setWindowTitle(_translate("Second", "Second"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Second", "Show Input"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Second", "TextLabel"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_First(object):
    def setupUi(self, First):
        First.setObjectName("First")
        First.resize(195, 134)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(First)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 80, 111, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(First)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.retranslateUi(First)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(First)

    def retranslateUi(self, First):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        First.setWindowTitle(_translate("First", "First"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("First", "Send to Second"))


class Ui_Second(object):
    def setupUi(self, Second):
        Second.setObjectName("Second")
        Second.resize(195, 134)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Second)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 80, 111, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Second)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 40, 55, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Second)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Second)

    def retranslateUi(self, Second):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Second.setWindowTitle(_translate("Second", "Second"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Second", "Show Input"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Second", "TextLabel"))


class First(QDialog):

    signal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(First, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui = Ui_First()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.lineEdit.setFocus()   # +

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Send)

        self.show()

    def Send(self):
        UserInput = self.ui.lineEdit.text()

        foo = Second(self)                                 # + self.
        self.signal.emit(str(UserInput))

#        self.signal.connect(foo.Receive)
#        self.ui = Second()


class Second(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Second, self).__init__(parent)  

        self.ui = Ui_Second()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)      # - (self.Receive)

        parent.signal.connect(self.Receive)                 # +++

        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def Receive(self, strA):
        self.ui.label.setText(strA)
        self.ui.label.adjustSize()    # +


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = First()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]